# Find closest pixel which matches color

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make an autohotkey script which finds all available healthbars on screen. I want the script to do two things:

1. Find the closest healthbar by color
2. Move the mouse to the leftmost part of the healthbar

However, pixelsearch only returns the first pixel it finds.
Is there a better way to either return all pixels of a color, then get the closest healthbar to the center of the screen, and finally move the mouse to the farthest left pixel of the healthbar?

Here is an image of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: Healthbars]

I am not sure if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: This 3th health bar position, is always near the center? You may try use a region enclosing only this health bar.
After find this health bar, if your `X1` is smaller than your `X2`(and the same for `Y1` and `Y2`) in `pixelsearch`, your `OutputVarX` and `OutputVarY` will be the top left position of the health bar...

Answer (score 0):

Consider using FindText (library created by an FeiYue, you can find it on the AHK forum) because it's way faster than standard AHK functions and you won't get any false positives from other things on the screen being the same color.

If closer healthbars are bigger on the screen, you can use that to determine distance. Just find all groupings of NxN pixels which have the color you're looking for and the sequence with the most consecutive NxN groupings is your closest healthbar. There's a bit of trial and error there, but you can get it to be pretty accurate.